# Conflating XML tree when child element equals parent element

Tags: xml, xslt

I use XSLT.

Assume this very simple XML:

```
<ROOT>
  <ELEMENT>
    <ELEMENT>content of ELEMENT</ELEMENT>
  </ELEMENT>
</ROOT>
```

How can I conflate the XML hierarchy in XSLT when the name of the child node is equal to the name of its parent? The resulting XML should look like:

```
<ROOT>
   <ELEMENT>content of ELEMENT</ELEMENT>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: And for <ROOT><ELEM><ELEM>aaa</ELEM><ELEM>bbb</ELEM></ELEM></ROOT> the desired result is what?  For <ROOT><ELEM>aaa<ELEM>bbb</ELEM><ELEM>ccc</ELEM></ELEM></ROOT>?  And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think it's hard to give a good answer without seeing a more complex example.  What should be the result if the input XML is: `<ROOT><ELEMENT><ELEMENT>hello</ELEMENT><OTHER>hi there</OTHER><ELEMENT><ELEMENT>howdy</ELEMENT>g'day</ELEMENT></ELEMENT></ROOT>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question doesn't make a whole lot of sense; especially when the XML is even slightly more complicated, like in the examples from C. M. Sperberg-McQueen and JLRishe or if an attribute is present on either the parent or the child/children.

However, if I wanted to do this and the XML structure was as simple as your example, this is how I would do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[name()=name(*)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there were attributes in the parent and you wanted to propagate those down, you could do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[name()=name(*)]" priority="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[name()=name(../*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you first copy the /ROOT/ELEMENT/ELEMENT element and then delete /ROOT/ELEMENT you can put back the copied ELEMENT element again...